# Mule 3.9 logs HTTP response sending task failed with error: Locally closed

Tags: mule

I use ApiKit to receive queries. Occasionally I get the following line in a log file:

```
WARN  org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.grizzly.ResponseCompletionHandler - HTTP response sending task failed with error: Locally closed
```

It seems that in this case the integration has not sent a response to the party that called the integration. I thought that there might be a sort of timeout before ApiKit closes the connection to caller but based on timestamps that might not be the case as everything happens within a second.

In this case the payload is sent to Artemis queue before this warning and despite the warning the message is read from Artemis normally and the whole flow works otherwise just fine besides this warning and not sending the response.

So, am I correct when I think that this warning is an indication why the response is not sent? In addition to that what can be done to prevent this situation?

Comment: What is the exact version of Mule? Are there more lines to the error message?

Comment: It is version 3.9.0. No, that is the only line line of error message. Previous line is my own logging (info level) that says that the message was sent to Artemis. Then is this warning line and the next is info line that tells that the message is read from Artemis. In a normal situation both of those lines, except the warning line, are logged too.

Comment: Is there high load or high resource usage?

Comment: That's a good point and I have to take a better look at that.